# Создать единичную матрицу (ojAlgo)

Tags: java

Речь конкретно о библиотеке ojAlgo. Мне нужно выполнить операцию Matrix - 1. Как мне создать единичную матрицу, чтобы вычесть её из другой матрицы?

Comment: [Matrix.identity](http://ojalgo.org/generated/org/ojalgo/matrix/jama/Matrix.html#identity(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал массив двумерный массив, заполнив диагональ единицами. После чего сделал из него матрицу.

```
double[][] unit = new double[n][n]; // Единичная матрица
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    if (i == j)
                        unit[i][j] = 1;
MatrixStore<Double> e = Primitive64Store.FACTORY.columns(unit);
e = e.subtract(e);
```